# How to display the data displayed on the page in the block that will be placed in the header region?

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

I made a custom module that does this:

When a user writes in the url the city of **London**: 
`http://drupalsite/web/weather/London` 
Website **api.openweathermap.org** provides data using API and user gets the London weather data on the page:

[image]

#### But I want the weather data to also be displayed in the header region in **block**.

How to implement this?

Comment: I'm not sure to totally understand your question.
Where is the template used by your module?
You module display a block?
You want to see those values inside the header region and in the content region?
Or only in the header?

Answer (score 0):

**Split the values from the API** in your module with php and later use your **new variables** for output.